# Using a UIScrollView zoomToRect works when zooming to an images width but not its height

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uiscrollview

I am trying to zoom into a UIImage so I can see as much of the photo as possible without showing white space. Thus in portrait I want to zoom so that the shorter of the two sides of the image fits fully in the screen. All of the following code is in `viewDidLoad`.

I have the `UIImageView` and `UIScrollView` set up as follows:

```
self.scrollView.delegate = self;
self.scrollView.contentSize = self.imageView.image.size;
self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT);
```

At this point zooming and scrolling within the `UIScrollView` works perfectly.

Then I implement an `if-else` so that when the picture is taller than it is wide I call:

`[self.scrollview zoomToRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, IMAGE_WIDTH, 1)];`

This works perfectly. The width of the image fills the width of the screen and I can only scroll up and down.

But when I call the exact same function for the height:

`[self.scrollview zoomToRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, IMAGE_HEIGHT)];`

Nothing! No zoom at all as if the function was never called. But I set a breakpoint and stepped through the code in the debugger and everything was called perfectly, even the `CGRectMake` function itself. What's going on?

Comment: This is zooming to a rect that is effectively just a line...is this what you want to happen?

Comment: Yes because `zoomToRect` simply zooms to put the entire rect on screen so the the other dimension is arbitrary.

Comment: Hmm, then one of the dimensions may take precedence...how would it know which one is arbitrary?  Perhaps width is taking precedence if the aspect ratio is off, thus rendering your second method futile?

Comment: What do you mean the width would take precedence? The method does the minimum amount of work to put the whole rectangle onto the screen so with a width of 1 and the height of the image it should just zoom such that the top and bottom of the image are lined up with the top and bottom of the screen. It is not trying to actually zoom into the whole rectangle.

Comment: I attempted the same method as above but with a width conforming to the aspect ratio `(IMAGE_HEIGHT * 360) / 480` and it made no difference.

Comment: Hmm, just making an educated guess.  I worked a little with that method before...sorry I am not more help...

Comment: Thanks for trying. What's weird is I'm pretty sure it work before then I changed something and changed it back and now I can't get it to work again. I'm starting to think that I imagined it working :P

Comment: Well I tried the same thing as before but this time I changed it to `(IMAGE_HEIGHT * 320)/367` which is the correct value (because of `UINavigationController` and `UITabBar`) and it worked! Thanks for the help. If you want to formally answer I'll accept it so this is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments above, make sure you select a rect with both a width and a height for the given aspect ratio you want to zoom to.

```
[self.scrollview zoomToRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, IMAGE_WIDTH * WIDTH_OF_VIEW / HEIGHT_OF_VIEW, IMAGE_HEIGHT)];
```

Answer (score 0):

The zoomToRect method also has the argument 'animated', ie:

```
[self.scrollview zoomToRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, IMAGE_HEIGHT) animated:NO];
```

So that might be causing the problem.  If not, you could try this:

```
CGFloat scale1 = IMAGE_WIDTH / self.scrollview.frame.size.width;
CGFloat scale2 = IMAGE_HEIGHT / self.scrollview.frame.size.height;
[self.scrollview setZoomScale:MAX(scale1, scale2) animated:NO];
[self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0,0,0,0) animated:NO];
```

Comment: I didn't include `animated` in the question as it is unimportant here. But I got everything to work anyway - see comments above!